# Which vector space axiom(s) is (are) going to fail if we take $\mathbb{C}$ as our set of vectors and $\mathbb{Z}$ as our set of scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the standard definition of vector space:

> Let $F$ be a field, and let $X$ be a non-empty set such that

> (A0) for each pair $x, y$ of elements of $X$, there exists a unique element $x + y$ in $X$;

> (M0) for each element $\alpha \in F$ and for each element $x \in X$, there exists a unique element $\alpha x$ in $X$;

> (A1) for any elements $x, y, z$ in $X$, we have
> $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$;

> (A2) there exists a unique element $\mathbf{0}$ in $X$ such that $x + \mathbf{0} = x$ for every element $x \in X$;

> (A3) for each element $x$ in $X$, there exists an element (in fact a *unique* element) $-x$ in $X$ such that $x+(-x) = \mathbf{0}$;

> (A4) for any elements $x$ and $y$ in $X$, we have $x+y = y+x$;

> (M1) for any elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $F$ and for any element $x$ in $X$, we have
> $(\alpha + \beta) x = \alpha x + \beta x$;

> (M2) for any elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $F$ and for any element $x$ in $X$, we have
> $(\alpha \beta) x = \alpha (\beta x)$;

> (M3) for any element $\alpha$ in $F$ and for any elements $x$ and $y$ in $X$, we have
> $\alpha (x + y) = \alpha x + \alpha y$; and

> (M4) for any element $x$ in $X$, we have $1x = x$,  where $1$ is the multiplicative identity element in the field $F$.

The set $X$ then is our set of vectors, whereas $F$ is our set of scalars.

Now my question is, what if we take $X \colon= \mathbb{C}$, the set of complex numbers, as our set of vectors but take the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers, which is *not* a field but is rather only a commutative ring with unity, as our set of scalars? The above axioms (A0) through (A4) and (M0) through (M4) still hold, don't they? Where is it that we run into problems with this particular  choice?

Comment: As the other answers say, replacing the field $F$ by a commutative ring $R$ gives you an object called a module. It's worth noting, though, that modules are much more complicated objects than vector spaces, which are completely classified by their dimension (at least, assuming the axiom of choice). The category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, for example, is exactly the category of abelian groups, and it includes things like $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{R}$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A "vector-space" over a ring is called a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). As you say, there is nothing in the axioms for a vector-space that require a field structure. However, having the field structure allows leads to better behaviour and allows us to prove theorems such as "Every vector space has a basis." and "The cardinality of a basis is unique." Over a module these theorems need not hold, and if you see the proofs of these theorems for vector-spaces you will see that they use the existence of inverses in $F$.

Answer (score 2):

None fail. What you have is what is called a (unital) (left) module.

More generally, if $R$ is any ring, then a left $R$-module is a set $M$, together with a binary operation $+\colon M\times M\to M$ (usually written in infix notation, so the result of applying $+$ to the pair $(m,n)$ is denote $m+n$), and a function $\cdot\colon R\times M\to M$ such that:

1. $+$ is associative: for all $x,y,z\in M$, $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$.
2. $+$ is commutative: for all $x,y\in M$, $x+y=y+x$.
3. $+$ has an identity: there exists an element $0\in M$ such that for all $x\in M$, $0+x=x+0=x$.
4. Existence of additive inverses: for all $x\in M$ there exists $y\in M$ such that $x+y=y+x=0$.
5. Associativity of $\cdot$: for all $\alpha,\beta\in R$ and all $x\in M$, we have $(\alpha\beta)\cdot x = \alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot x)$.
6. Left distributivity of $\cdot$: for all $\alpha\in R$ and $x,y\in M$, $\alpha\cdot(x+y) = (\alpha\cdot x) + (\alpha\cdot y)$.
7. Right distributivity of $\cdot$: for all $\alpha,\beta\in R$ and $x\in M$, $(\alpha+\beta)\cdot x = (\alpha\cdot x)+(\beta\cdot x)$.

Note that the $+$ on the left hand side of 7 is the sum of the ring $R$, and the $+$ on the right hand side is the $+$ of $M$.

If in addition we have that $R$ is a ring with unity, and we have

8. For all $x\in M$, $1\cdot x = x$.

Then we say $M$ is a (left) *unital* $R$-module.

Axioms 1-4 say that $(M,+,0)$ is an *abelian group*. Axioms 5, 6, and 7 define a "scalar multiplication" that is compatible with that structure. Axiom $8$ makes the unity of $R$ act in a natural way.

One can also define right $R$-modules, when the operation $\cdot$ is defined on $M\times R$ and maps to $M$.

A *vector space* is a (left) unital $R$-module where $R$ is actually a field.

These structures are consistent. What starts failing are many of the **theorems** for vector spaces. For example:

1. It is no longer necessarily true that every (unital) module has a basis.
2. It is no longer necessarily true that every generating set contains a basis.
3. It is no longer necessarily true that every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.
4. It is no longer necessarily true that two bases, if they exist, must have the same cardinality.

And more...

When the ring $R$ is the integers, what you get is in fact just an abelian group structure. So every a unital $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure is equivalent to an abelian group structure. What you describe is the abelian group structure of $\mathbb{C}$ under addition.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any problems. This is the $\Bbb Z$-module structure of $\Bbb C$, which is equivalent to the abelian group structure of $\Bbb C$. We just don't call $R$-modules vector spaces unless $R$ is a field.

Comment: To be more precise, they are *unital* $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (because of M4).

Answer (score 1):

There are no problems, except for that fact that $\mathbb Z$ is not a field.

That is, there are no problems *until* you start attempting to apply theorems which require the scalars to form a field.

For example, here is a theorem about vector spaces:

> For any vector space $X$ over any field $F$, and for any $x \in X$, the operations of addition and scalar multiplication on $X$ restrict to a vector space structure on the set $Fx = \{\alpha x \mid \alpha \in F\}$.

If you apply this to $x=1 \in \mathbb C$ using $F=\mathbb Z$ then you get $Fx=\mathbb Z$ which is definitely *not* a vector space (no matter *what* field you choose for scalars). What went wrong? Well, $F=\mathbb Z$ is not a field, that's what went wrong.

If that's not convincing enough there are plenty of deeper theorems where things go wrong, for example theorems about linear independence and bases. Here's an example:

> If $X$ is a vector space over a field $F$, and if there exists finitely many elements $x_1,...,x_K \in X$ such that every $x \in X$ can be expressed as a linear combination $x=\alpha_1 x_1 + ... + \alpha_K x_K$, then there exist finitely many elements $b_1,...,b_K \in X$ such that every $x \in X$ can be expressed ***uniquely*** as a linear combination
> $$x = \beta_1 b_1 + ... + \beta_K b_K
> $$
> That is, the sequence of coefficients $\beta_1,...,\beta_K$ is *uniquely* determined by $x$ and the sequece of elements $b_1,...,b_K$.

If you take your scalars to be $\mathbb Z$ then this is just plain false: $X = \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is a counterexample. In essence, we have run into the problem that multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb Z$ do not generally exist.

---

In summary, you can write any axioms you want and call the resulting kind of mathematical structure a BLURG, but you cannot expect theorems about vector spaces to be true for BLURGs.

---

One last point of emphasis: I would say that the definition of a vector space presented in your post has a subtle flaw. The concept being defined there is not just a *vector space*, instead, the concept being defined is a *vector space over the field $F$*. Also, a well written definition should more clearly separate what is given (in this case $F$, $X$, and the operations (A0) and (M0)) from the defining properties. So I would suggest that the opening clauses of the definition of a vector space be rewritten like this:

> Given a field $F$, a *vector space over $F$* consists of a set $X$, (A0) a binary operation $+$ on $X$ denoted $x + y$, and (M0) a function $F \times X \to X$ denoted $\alpha x$, such that the following properties hold: (A1-4), (M1-4).